# Is it okay for my Python packages to be installed at a different location than where Python is installed?

Tags: python

I installed Python for all users here:
`C:\Program Files\Python310`

But all my packages are being installed here:
`C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages`
after the message `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable` appears.

Everything works fine now, but will this pose a problem in the future? Should I uninstall python and reinstall it only for my user?

Here are my enviornment variables:

`C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts` -- a warning reccomended I add this when I tried to install a package

`C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts\`

`C:\Program Files\Python310\`

Comment: This is in fact perfectly normal and as it should be.

Comment: @KonradRudolph if I let's say download a newer version of python, will it pose a problem that my packages are installed at a different location than my python installation?

Comment: As a general rule, different versions of Python must use different package installations. But Python already takes care of this: notice that your package path includes the version number, `Python310`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want everyone on the computer to be able to use the packages, this is a problem.

But if you only want them on your account its fine.

Comment: Do you know why the packages are being installed to my user rather than to where python is installed? Is this normal for when you install python to all users?

Comment: Th reason is because your not running the install command on an admin Command Prompt, just right click run as administrator and it should be fixed.

Comment: Is it best practice to install my pacakges as administrator (as you say) or to do it the way I have been doing it?

Comment: Depends on use case.